# How to recreate a specific sound in FL Studio 12?

Tags: sound-design, sound, sound-libraries, plug-ins, fl-studio

**THE SITUATION:**

I would like to recreate a specific sound.

Here you can hear the it:

From 0:02 to 0:05.
It repeat itself three times.

I spent a lot of time in FL Studio, searching through all the packs and trying several plugins but i wasn't successful.

**THE QUESTION:**

Do you have any idea about how can i recreate that sound?
If not exactly like that, at least something similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a guitar sample with some filter. You can try to take a acoustic guitar vst or sample and combine it with a low pass.

Comment: By the way do you have in mind some good acoustic guitar vst?

Comment: DSK AkoustiK GuitarZ is pretty nice :)

Comment: Ok i manage to create something similar using vst BooBass plugin. Low filter was also important. If you want to write as reply i can check as correct since you helped to get to the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a guitar sample with some filter. You can try to take a acoustic guitar vst or sample and combine it with a low pass filter.

DSK AkoustiK GuitarZ should be pretty nice for that :)